# Broken Markdown Formatting

Tags: bug, status-completed, html, markdown

I wasn't sure where else to put it, so I decided upon Meta.Programmers.StackExchange.

If you evaluate the html generated for [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site/46763#46763), you will notice that it generates mismatched tags when making bold-italic text:

```
<em><strong>Platform</em></strong> ...
<em><strong>Deadline</em></strong>/<em><strong>Budget</em></strong>...
<em><strong>Content</em></strong>...
```

I'm not particularly a W3C validation nut, but surely we can all agree this is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see:

***Bold and Italic***

`***Bold and Italic***`

This produces

`<em><strong>Bold and Italic</em></strong>`

I simply entered a space in the post, pressed the save button, and this re-rendered the post with correct output. The original post was from December 2008 so it reflects an earlier output parser.